# set table head fixed and scrolling body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have that which `thead` is fixed o top and the `tbody`  shows a vertical scroll with this css

```
thead{
    display: block;
}
tbody {
    display:block;
    height:500px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

But the problem is that  the `thead` fields width are not adjusted to the `tbody` fields width
 Hoy I can make that the head and the body fields to have the same width?(without the css it have the same width)

Comment: can you please put your code working snippet

Comment: put in the html too, as a snippet would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Try
Add .navbar-fixed-top and include a .container or .container-fluid to center and pad navbar content.

Answer (score -1):

```
thead{
  display: block;
}

tbody {
 position:absolute; 
 display:block;
 height:500px;
 Width:200px;
}
```

try this...

Comment: doesn't work , thead width is still different than tbdoy witdth

Comment: can share your code because this is just a line of code rigth ? . I can't even try to run this